# When would you use strings instead of characters?

Tags: c, string, character

When is it appropriate to use strings instead of characters?  What about vice-versa?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It depends upon the purpose of the program. Nothing in general as a rule.

Comment: I for one think this is a perfectly reasonable question.  Why was this closed?  It's not written very well, but the actual question being asked - why would you use a string instead of a character and vice-versa - I think is actually a very reasonable thing to ask.

Comment: Maybe making your question a little clearer would get you some answers. What do you think is the difference between a string and a character?

Comment: @templatetypedef: I'm hesitant to vote to re-open a question phrased like this one is. If you have a direction in mind, please consider editing the question to make it answerable. I'm always impressed to read your answers, but opening the question as it is will also invite less than stellar answers.

Comment: When do you use words words instead of letters?

Comment: @Cody Gray- I've reworded the question.  Can you check back in?

Comment: @templatetypedef: Thanks for that. My reopen vote is cast.

Answer (score 4):

Strings and characters represent fundamentally different concepts.

A character is a single, indivisible unit representing some sort of glyph.  When working with a character, you are guaranteed to have a single character, no more or no less.  Functions that work with characters are best suited for cases where you know this to be true.  For example, if you were writing "Hangman" and wanted to process a user's guess, it would make sense for the function that processes the guess to take a character rather than a string, since you know for a fact that the input to that function should always be a single letter.

A string is a composite type formed by taking zero or more characters and putting them together.  Strings are typically used to represent text, which can have an arbitrary length, including having zero length.  Functions that work on strings are best suited for cases where the input is known to be made of letters, but it's unclear how many letters there are going to be.

One other option is to use a fixed-length array of characters, which is ideal for the situation where you know that you have **exactly** k characters for some k.  This does not come up very much, but it's another option.

In short, use characters when you know that you need to work on a piece of text that is just one glyph long.  Use strings when you don't know the length of the input in advance.  Use fixed-sized arrays when you know for a fact that the input has some particular length.